# message trying to get property of non-object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

View:
Any one help me to solve this issue,i'm getting following error A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: users/dataupdate.php

Line Number: 5
```

This is my view page

**dataupdate.php:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>user_controller/dataupdate/<?php echo $id;?>">
    <table width="280" border="1" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php $result->name;?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="test" name="cnum" value="<?php $result->email;?>></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>mobile</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php $result->mobile;?>></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"></td>

      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is my controller

**user_controller.php:**

```
<?php
    class user_controller extends CI_controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent:: __construct();
            //$this->load->helper('form');
            //$this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('user_model');
        }
        function add()
        {
            $data['title']="add";
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("name","Name","required");//text fildname,userdefine name
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("email","email","required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("password","password","required");
            $this->form_validation->set_rules("mobile","mobile","required");


            if($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $this->user_model->insert($_POST);
                redirect("user_controller/display");
            }
            $this->load->view('users/add',$data);
        }
        function display()
        {
            $data['result']=$this->user_model->datadisplay();
            $this->load->view('users/datadisplay',$data);
        }
        function deletedata($id)
        {
            $data['result']=$this->user_model->deletequery($id);
            redirect("user_controller/display");
        }

        function updatedata($id)
        {
             $data['result']=$this->user_model->datadisplay(array("id"=>$id));
             if($this->form_validation->run())
             {
                  $_POST['id']=$id;
                  $id=$this->user_model->update($_POST);
             }
             $data['id']=$id;
             $this->load->view('users/dataupdate',$data);
        }
    }
?>
```

This is my model

**user_model.php:**

```
<?php
class user_model extends CI_model
{
    function insert($options=array()){
        if(isset($options['name']))//userdefine name
            $this->db->set('name',$options['name']);//db colomn name,text field name
        if(isset($options['email']))
            $this->db->set('email',$options['email']);
        if(isset($options['password']))
            $this->db->set('password',md5($options['password']));
        if(isset($options['mobile']))
            $this->db->set('mobile',$options['mobile']);
        $this->db->insert('user');
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    function datadisplay()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user');
        if(isset($options['id']))
            $this->db->where('id',$options['id']);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    function deletequery($id)
    {
        $this->db->delete('user',array('id'=>$id));
    }

    function update($options=array())
    {
        if(isset($options['name']))//userdefine name
            $this->db->set('name',$options['name']);//db colomn name,text field name
        if(isset($options['email']))
            $this->db->set('email',$options['email']);
        if(isset($options['mobile']))
            $this->db->set('mobile',$options['mobile']);
        if(isset($options['id']))
            $this->db->where('id',$options['id']);
        $query=$this->db->update('user');
        return $query;
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Try to add `datadisplay($id)` and change `if(isset($id)) $this->db->where('id',$id);` in datadisplay method in your model.

Answer (score 0):

you should assign value into another variable than use it.

```
<?php    
$tempname = $result[0]->name; 
$email = $result[0]->email;
$mob = $result[0]->mobile;
?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>user_controller/dataupdate/<?php echo $id;?>">
<table width="280" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $tempname;?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="test" name="cnum" value="<?php echo $email;?>></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>mobile</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $mob;?>></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: users/dataupdate.php

Line Number: 3

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: users/dataupdate.php

Line Number: 4

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: users/dataupdate.php

Line Number: 5

Comment: it is printing all records

Answer (score 0):

When you get the message "trying to get the property of a non-object" in PHP, it means that you are trying to access an attribute of an object, where the object does not exist.

Consider this as an example.  An object Car $car exists in your code and a Car object has a public attribute $speed. Normally you can access speed of the $car object by $car->speed. If somehow $car is set to null or some other value, where it is not a Car object, you will receive the error when attempting to access the $speed attribute of a Car.

Before you attempt to access the speed attribute you could do something like:

```
if (is_a($car, 'Car')) {
    //do whatever you want when $car is a Car object
} else {
    //do whatever you want when $car is not a Car object
}
```

You could also use this:

```
if ($car instanceof Car) {
    //do whatever you want when $car is a Car object
} else {
    //do whatever you want when $car is not a Car object
}
```

And finally, you can do this, which will suppress the exception, when $car is not a Car object:

```
if (@$car->speed)
    //do whatever you want when $car is a Car object
} else {
    //do whatever you want when $car is not a Car object
}
```

If $car is always supposed to be a Car object, and you're receiving the error, the best thing to do would be to avoid all of the additional logic and determine where your $car object is being corrupted and fix it.

Comment: At the locations where you have something like $result->name, you could temporarily use @$result->name ?: '';. This will suppress the exception, but ultimately you need to figure out why $result is not properly set.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use the object or variable like `@$variable`

```
 <input name="ftp_name"  value="<?php echo $ftpDetails->ftp_name;?>" type="text">
```

change to:

```
<input name="ftp_name"  value="<?php echo @$ftpDetails->ftp_name;?>" type="text">
```